# composer - update cakephp app

Tags: php, cakephp, composer-php

I have a cakephp app with following in the composer.json

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.4.16",
    "cakephp/cakephp": "~3.0",
    ...
},
```

If I update it using: `composer require cakephp/cakephp:"~3.3"`, I get:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.4.16",
    "cakephp/cakephp": "~3.3",
    ...
},
```

however, cakephp v3.3 requires php version 5.5.9, so I wonder what composer command should I use to update json file to the following

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "cakephp/cakephp": "~3.3",
    ...
},
```

Comment: What's stopping you from editing composer.json manually and change the PHP version to `5.5.9`?

Comment: Nothing that's what I did, but it was strange to me composer didn't update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of a dependency manager is so you don't have to worry about dependency trees yourself.

Since you depend on `cakephp/cakephp` `~3.3`, and [it depends on `php` `>=5.5.9`](https://packagist.org/packages/cakephp/cakephp), your application implicitly depends on that same version.

This doesn't conflict with your current dependency on `php` `>=5.4.16`, but you can probably remove your PHP dependency entirely.

Comment: Thanks. I just thought it should be updated automatically by 'composer update'. According your answer, app depends on highest version of some library (if that lib is mentioned more then once). If this is true I wonder what would happen if for example I have two plugins and one requires jQuery 1.7 and the other jQuery 1.9. Will that mean my project depends on jQuery 1.9? What if the first plugin works with 1.7 but not with 1.9?

Comment: @Kupe3, I think you're misunderstanding the [`update`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#update) command. Your `composer.json` file contains the dependencies that you have _explicitly asked for_, either by modifying the file manually or via the `require` command. `composer update` doesn't modify `composer.json`. It takes that file as its _input_, searches for newer versions of things that match that input, installs them, and updates `composer.lock`. It will never modify `composer.json`.

Comment: @Kupe3, part of what Composer does is to build a [dependency graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_graph). It takes your explicit dependencies, looks at _their_ dependencies, and so on, attempting to resolve a set of packages to install. In this there is no conflict: You need `php` `>=5.4.16` and also `php` `>=5.5.9`. Any version of PHP at or above 5.5.9 satisfies both requirements. If there _is_ a conflict, e.g. `foo/bar` `~1.7` and `foo/bar` `~1.9`, Composer will tell you it can't resolve the dependencies and fail. Then you have to act, e.g. by replacing or upgrading a dependency.